# The value was either too small or too large for an unsigned byte C#

Tags: c#, winforms, byte, overflowexception

I have 2 methods, shown below, and i can't get it to work.  I am trying to open a `.png` file from a `OpenFileDialog` and display it on a `ImageBox`:

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this string input)
{
    List<byte> splitBytes = new List<byte>();
    string byteString = "";
    foreach (char i in input)
    {
        byteString += i;
        if (byteString.Length == 3)
        {
            splitBytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(byteString));
            byteString = "";
        }
    }
    if (byteString != "")
        splitBytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(byteString));
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(splitBytes.ToArray()))
    {
        var img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        Bitmap output = new Bitmap(img);
        return output;
    }
}

public static string StringFromFile(string input)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input);
    string file = string.Empty;
    while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        file += sr.Read();
    }
    return file;
}
```

In another file i tried to use the method:

```
OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
OFD.Filter = "Images (*.png)|*.png";
OFD.ShowDialog();
pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = StringToBitmapConverter.ToBitmap(StringToBitmapConverter.StringFromFile(OFD.FileName));
```

But I get this exception:

> System.OverflowException: 'Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.'

Please help!
I am using these methods in a class called `StringToBitmapConverter`, and there is an error that is giving me trouble, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

So according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk.aspx) `Convert.ToByte(string value)`:

> Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer.

And the method will throw an `OverflowException` if:

> value represents a number that is less than Byte.MinValue or greater than Byte.MaxValue.

So the value of `byteString` must be less than 0 or greater than 255 at this line:

`splitBytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(byteString));`

Comment: But how would i fix the problem, that is what i am asking help with.

Comment: @Techcraft7 it depends on what you are wanting to do, it is not exactly clear what you are trying to do with `splitBytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(byteString));`. EDIT: I just looked at your code, you are trying to use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(byteString) to read the bytes of the file to open it as a bitmap, THIS WILL NEVER WORK. `Encoding.ASCII` can't represent every possible byte value.

Comment: Then how would i do it?  can you make a code sample?

Comment: @Techcraft7 Do what? you need to update your question explaining what the file format is and what you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use try { } catch to catch the error or use [byte.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to only convert those numbers that are actually convertable.

Reading text from a File can be done by [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_)

Your algorythm splits the read text into characterblocks of 3 and interprets the text as byte:

"23405716119228936" -> 234,57,161,192,289,36  .... 289 does notfit into a byte -> exception. Check the files content.

```
if (byte.TryParse(byteString, out var b))
{
    splitBytes.Add(b);
}
else
{
    // this thing is not convertable to byte, do something with it....
}
```

Edit#1:

I guess reading in PNG-Files as "string" and converting them as you do does not work.

PNG Files have an internal format, they are encoded. See 
https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/
or 
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

They are not strings that you can simply group into 3 chars, convert to byte and reinterprete as memory string.

For giggles try this on your file to see what is your input.:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var s in Make3CharChunks(File.ReadAllText( /*your file path here*/ ""))
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> Make3CharChunks(string s)
                        => s.Aggregate(new List<string>(), (acc, c) =>
                {
                    if (acc.Any() && acc.Last().Count() < 3)
                        acc[acc.Count - 1] = $"{acc.Last()}{c}";
                    else
                        acc.Add(c.ToString());

                    return acc;
                });
}
```

Comment: When i said <br>splitBytes.Add(Byte.TryParse(byteString, out byte result));<br>it says that it cant convert byte to bool. (CS1503)

Comment: When i did that code it throws another error on this line: var img = Image.FromStream(ms); it says that "The parameter isn't valid"

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is trying to open a png you can throw away most all of your code and simplify it to

```
OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
OFD.Filter = "Images (*.png)|*.png";
var result = OFD.ShowDialog()    
if(result == DialogResult.OK) //You need to check to see if they clicked OK or Cancel.
{
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

    var oldImage = pictureBox1.BackgroundImage
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(OFD.FileName); //Shouold be Image, not BackgroundImage for a picture box.
    if(oldImage != null)
    {
        oldImage.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: well, i am trying to make a pack of .dll files that people can use for software, and my first is string to bitmap.